# Importing data to Excel from Google

Tags: excel

Here's the deal. I have an Excel spreadsheet with the following information - Job Title, Company Name, Phone Number (BLANK), Location.

Is there a way I can automatically search the company name + location on Google and have the phone number cell be automatically populated by the search results?

The problem I'm running into, as far as I can tell, is that I'm trying to pull information from a Google search and not a specific URL.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I have used API's, webhooks, googletoexcel websites, WEBSERVICE function in Excel, etc.